# CodeIgniter: передача переменных из файла.php -> в файл.js

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые кодеры.
Хочу поинтересоваться, как из файла.php передать $переменную -> в файл.js. И что бы она вывелась на странице, как в случае с кодом в `<?php echo $a;?>`. Ведь php код игнорится в файле с расширением *.js, а поменять расширение - не вариант((.
 Могу привести код **файла.js**

```
function share42(f,u,t,m1,m2){if(!u)u=location.href;if(!t)t=document.title;u=encodeURIComponent(u);t=encodeURIComponent(t);if(!m1)m1=150;if(!m2)m2=20;document.write('<span id="share42">');var s=new Array('"" onclick="return fav(this);" title="Сохранить в избранное браузера"','"http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=addShare&st._surl='+u+'&title='+t+'" title="Добавить в Одноклассники"','"#" onclick="window.open(\'http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url='+u+'\', \'_blank\', \'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=200, top=200, width=554, height=421, toolbar=0, status=0\');return false" title="Поделиться В Контакте"','"http://connect.mail.ru/share?url='+u+'&title='+t+'" title="Поделиться в Моем Мире@Mail.Ru"','"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+u+'&t='+t+'" title="Поделиться в Facebook"','"http://twitter.com/share?text='+t+'&url='+u+'" title="Добавить в Twitter"','"http://www.livejournal.com/update.bml?event='+u+'&subject='+t+'" title="Опубликовать в LiveJournal"','"http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+u+'&title='+t+'" title="Добавить в Linkedin"','"http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&output=popup&bkmk='+u+'&title='+t+'" title="Сохранить закладку в Google"','"#" onclick="print();return false" title="Распечатать"','"#" onclick="return up()" title="Наверх"');for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)document.write('<a rel="nofollow" style="display:block;width:32px;height:32px;margin:0 0 6px;outline:none;background:url('+f+'icons.png) -'+32*i+'px 0" href='+s[i]+' target="_blank"></a>');document.write('</span>'); window.onload=function(){var p=document.getElementById('share42');function m(){var top=Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);if(top+m2<m1){p.style.top=m1-top+'px';}else{p.style.top=m2+'px';}}m();window.onscroll=m;}}function fav(a){title=document.title;url=document.location;try{window.external.AddFavorite(url,title);}catch(e){try{window.sidebar.addPanel(title,url,"");}catch(e){if(typeof(opera)=="object"){a.rel="sidebar";a.title=title;a.url=url;return true;}else{alert('Нажмите Ctrl-D, чтобы добавить страницу в закладки');}}}return false;};var t;function up(){var top=Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);if(top>0){window.scrollBy(0,-200);t=setTimeout('up()',20);}else clearTimeout(t);return false;};
```

Там, где момент в самом начале `title=`"**Сохранить в избранное браузера**", именно на месте "**Сохранить в избранное браузера**" нужно вставить ту самую переменную из файла php.
А еще лучше сразу туда вставить значение сокращенного кода на примере

```
<?php echo lang('menu_main');?>
```

Спасибо заранее за ответ!

Comment: Всё. Разобрался

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно писать значение в скрытое поле с помощью PHP, а при выполнении JS скрипта читать его значение в переменную JS.

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="myval" value="<?echo '$value';?>">
</form>

var value = document.forms.myform.myval.value;
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то так.

```
var value = document.getElementByName("myval").value;
```

или так.

Comment: Умно сказали, а на примере?

Comment: Как хороший вариант.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: И как же, извините, вставить этот код в сплошной javascript код?
Там я в вопросе в самом низу написал, куда именно вставлять.. там ничего не получается

var value = document.forms.myform.myval.value;

или

var value = document.getElementByName("myval").value;

Comment: попробуйте элемент брать не через нейм, а через ай-ди, чтобы использовать оператор

    var value = document.getElementById("myval").value;

Comment: пока будут ставить, что ответ хорош, но мне то он не помогает!
конечно скажите, что руки из задницы, но по моему не внимательно читают, что именно я хочу сделать!

все равно вместо переменной, которой я задал,в браузере, вместо надписи выдает этот код:

var value = document.getElementById('myval').value;

Comment: с ординарными кавычками('myval') потому, так как если с двойными кавычками, в сплошном javascript коде если прописать так - 
var value = document.getElementById("myval").value;
то на выходе в браузере, где должна быть надпись "Сохранить в избранное браузера" тупо пишет:
var value = document.getElementById(

и всё!

Такое ощущение, что тут лишь бы всем ответить, но не понять, что именно надо!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. На php странице:

   echo '
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var MY_VAR = '.json_encode($my_var).';
   </script>
   ';
2. Использовать ajax и запросить нужные данные
3. уже предложенный вариант с input (можно и в скрытый div также добавить )

Comment: а про последние два пункта можно на примере кода? спасибо